# Can't run apps through ARC welder on windows or Chrome OS

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-arc

I've been trying to run a couple of apps from APK using the ARC welder extension on an Acer Chromebook. Every time that I get to the main function of the app, it crashes displaying the "shockwave crashed" image (frowning white puzzle piece on a black background).

I went to `chrome://settings/content` and tried to enable flash for the extension, but it says that flash is blocked by another extension. Can anyone help?

Comment: To be fair, Flash is irrelevant here; the image you're describing means a _plugin_ has crashed, not Flash specifically.

Answer (score 0):

For running android apk on Chromebook  create the virtual device that is AVD for that follow the below step : 
To run our app on a virtual Chrome OS device to that we have followed the following step :

**Install Chrome OS SDK add-ons for that**

1. In Android Studio, select Tools open SDK Manager.
    Click the SDK Update Sites tab.(3 tab)
2. Click Add at the bottom of the window. I'e +,
     Enter the following name and URL, then click OK

Name : Chrome OS Repository
URL:https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/addon2-1.xml

3. Click Add again.(+)Enter the following name and URL, then click 
   NAME :Chrome OS System URL:Images:https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/sys-img2-1.xml
4. Click Apply,Click the SDK Tools tab and select the checkbox for Chrome OS device,Click OK to install the Chrome OS device.

**Create an AVD using the AVD Manager**

From tablet category select Pixelbook (beta) hardware.
The default RAM size for an AVD is 1536 MB. I recommend increasing the RAM for the AVD to 2048 MB more than that...

After that loging using the Google account and drag and drop apk file .Application will be shown on app launcher.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that chrome://settings/content/flash is blocking ANY APP.

no way to turn it off.

maybe editing some of the chrome files... but dont know with one